# Reading excel file using OpnenXML -Reads rows which are blank

Tags: c#-4.0, openxml-sdk

Am using OpenXML to read Excel file, but getting some problem that it reads row which did not contain data. bellow is the code which reads the row.

```
 var firstOrDefault = sourceWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstOrDefault != null)
            {
                var sourceWorksheetRows = firstOrDefault.Elements<Row>();}
```

here when I count the sourceWorksheetRows it gives more count then records present in excel sheet. 
I tried to check null but its not working. How to implement the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the row is an empty record, just check the first cell (or any cell which is mandatory for the record) of the row, then check if CellValue is null or if "Trim(CellValue.Text).length == 0".

This is the solution I advise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the row is actually null? are there spaces or something in a column way out to the right?

Try and delete and re-insert the rows that should be null.

Comment: Actually it's free to user to upload excel file, some time it might be that it contains space, but have checked the file it did not contain any data. So need to have check not traverse those rows which did not contain data.

Comment: Please outline the problem better.  Give examples of data and exactly what you are wanting.  You don't have enough details here for anyone to answer the issue.

Comment: My problem is not to read the row which did not contain Data - means if the row contain space or any anything except text, date, numeric it should not read that.